# How can I use SQL to group and count data to get a specific output?

Tags: sql, mysql

query in sql to get the given output?

| cust_name | device | brand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'a' | 'settopbox' | 'airtel' |
| 'a' | 'settopbox' | 'dish' |
| 'a' | 'settopbox' | 'reliance' |
| 'b' | 'settopbox' | 'airtel' |
| 'd' | 'settopbox' | 'airtel' |
| 'd' | 'settopbox' | 'dish' |
| 'd' | 'settopbox' | 'reliance' |
| 'd' | 'settopbox' | 'hathway' |

Output:

| users | devices |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 |

I am trying in group by but not able to solve completely.

Comment: Your post is not clear, define what you need to do, how you need to do it, and since it looks like you have already done some attempts, share them at the bottom of your post.

Comment: Hi lemon , I got asked in an interview this question where interviewer asked me that how many users per how many devices. the table was like that only. can you help me?

Comment: Your source data has nothing that indicates a user. There is only one “device” value so any count would just be the count of all records - so maybe you mean count by brand? As @lemon said, the question is unclear - so either you need to clarify it or, if you don’t know what was being asked, you would have needed to ask the interviewer for clarification

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
select count(cust_name) as users, count(brand) as devices 
from [table name] 
group by users
```